# Click on back button destroys PHP Session

Tags: php, session

I need some help with a PHP/MySQL multiple choice quiz that I'm making for a website.i am in new in php.
 I'm having trouble with the logic of browser back button.if user click on 
browser back button inbetween quiz.it goes on end of quiz and redirect result page.i am doing like this:-

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions where id=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo $row['question_name'] ;
echo $row['answer1'] ;
echo $row['answer2'] ;
echo $row['answer3'] ;
echo $row['answer4'] ;
$_SESSION['exam']="true";
}
if($_SESSION['exam']=="false")
{
header('Location: expire.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you!

Comment: [Please, stop using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1238019) in new code, they are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead of, have a look on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

To start a new session or resume an old one, add `session_start()` to the top of each PHP page that uses sessions:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php

If you don't do that, your session won't work.

Comment: thanks for reply. i have add session_start() in connection.php

Answer (score 0):

Please use mysqli or PDO as mysql function already officially deprecated.

i'm not sure with the relation with your question and your code.
Is it ok

```
$_SESSION['exam']="true";
```

Or it should be

```
$_SESSION['exam']=="true";
```

What do you mean by

```
if($_SESSION['exam']=="false")
```

do you mean if session['exam'] is not set?
then it should

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['exam']))
```

Comment: means if user press pack button .The quiz will be ended and show result of quiz..like this site http://jambexampractice.com/practice-result.php

Comment: "click on window back button " mean browser's top back button or your own html button?

Comment: browser's top back button